# Make TextField wrap to a new line, not overflow

Tags: input, dart, textfield, flutter

I am using a simple `TextField` wrapped in a `Container`.
When the user types a long string, I want it to automatically wrap to a new line.

It currently flows off the screen, on a single line. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlimited number of lines

```
new TextField(..., maxLines: null)
```

or limited number of lines

```
new TextField(..., maxLines: 3)
```

This way it starts scrolling when the content exceeds the height of the input field

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html

Comment: Would be cool to have just a `wrapText` option to natively disallow line breaks and still prevent it from scrolling As a workaround I'm manually removing line-breaks on save using `.replaceAll('\n', ' ')`

Answer (score 4):

You have to set `maxLines` property to `null`. It default to 1.